# Surface Area integral of revolution

Tags: real-analysis, integration, graphing-functions, area

I have a problem understanding the definition of the surface area integral of a revolution . I know that we can obtain its volume using the disc method . The method defines the width of the disc as infinitely small (dx) , it is then pretty obvious that the integral is defined as the area made by each point multiplied by the width , which is dx .I found however by the definition of the surface area integral that the width is not defined as dx . Can somebody please clarify why it doesn't work the same way with surface areas ? ! 
thanks

Comment: I would say - instead of dx to take $ \text{ds} = \sqrt{1+\text{y'}^2}\,\text{dx}$

Comment: thanks for your answer but this is actually my question,  why would we take ds instead of dx . I have understood it already but I won't mind if someone can clarifies it more . :)

Comment: Sorry. Apparently I misunderstood  question.